# Why does the nested ul element bring down the entire li elements when hovering over one li element

Tags: html, css, sass

This is a two part question. **The first part** is my problem when hovering over an li element that is supposed to reveal a nested ul element. It brings the rest of the li tags at the bottom of the nested ul element. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it pushes the initial li elements downward. I wish someone can explain what I'm doing wrong. [Here is the code](http://codepen.io/blackyurizan/pen/ALQdax)

**The second question** I have is how do I create li elements that specificly have a hovering effect on them and not any nested li elements? I wanted to create a menu list that changes the color of the text when you hover over it, but I didn't want the nested li elements to also have the hover effect

HTML

```
<div id="container">

  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="">Fire</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">charmander</a></li>
          <li><a href="">magmar</a></li>
          <li><a href="">vulpix</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Grass</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">bulbasaur</a></li>
          <li><a href="">bellsprout</a></li>
          <li><a href="">oddish</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Electric</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">pichu</a></li>
          <li><a href="">magneton</a></li>
          <li><a href="">voltorb</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Water</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">squirtle</a></li>
          <li><a href="">poliwag</a></li>
          <li><a href="">krabby</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

SCSS

```
$green: #33cc33;
$blue : #0099ff;
$yellow: #ffcc00;
$red: #ff3333;
@mixin secondUl($color) {
        li {
            color: white;
            background: $color;
            min-width: 100px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
        }
        a {
            color: white;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            width:100% ;
            padding: 5px 0;
        }
    } //secondUl

#container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial,
    sans-serif;


    ul {


        margin: 15px 0;
        position: relative;

    } //ul
} //container

.list-inline {
    ul {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: -25% ;
        z-index: 2;
        display: none;
        li {
            display: inherit;
            min-width: 100px;
            margin: 0;
        } //li
    } //ul

    li:nth-of-type(1) ul {
        @include secondUl($red);
    }

    li:nth-of-type(2) ul {
        @include secondUl($green);
    }

    li:nth-of-type(3) ul {
        @include secondUl($yellow);
    }
    li:nth-of-type(4) ul {
        @include secondUl($blue);
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
      &:hover ul {
            display: block;
        }
    } //li 

     li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
        color: $red;
    }

     li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
        color: $green;
    }

    li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
        color: $yellow;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(4) a:hover {
        color: $blue;
    }


    &:first-child a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        text-transform: capitalization;
        font-weight: 600; 
        -webkit-transition: color 1s;
        transition: color 1s; 
        -moz-transition: color 1s;

    }
}//list-inline
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have used global css for `ul` under #container `#container ul {position:relative;}` this css will be apply on every child `ul` which is in `#container`, and its overriding `.list-inline ul{position:absolute}`, you need to set immediate child selector css `#container > ul {position:relative;}`.

For second ans. you need to do same thing, use `immediate child selector css`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRZVRO

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that  this ">" grabs the immediate child of the parent. I think I'm  going to code  better with this information

Answer (score 1):

**For problem 1** add `vertical-align:top` to your `li`

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    vertical-align: top;

  &:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
 }
```

**For Problem 2** use child instead of decendant selector. E.G:

```
> li:nth-child(1)>a:hover {
    color: $red;
}
```

See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrpVaV

Answer (score 0):

It works well. you have to add width of li

```
.list-inline li {
   min-width: 110px;
}
```

And

```
.list-inline li:hover ul {
   display: table;
}
```

**DEMO**

```
 https://codepen.io/Dhaarani/pen/vXpONj
```

Comment: @black_yurizan check this.